# Refactor code but different output

Tags: ruby, raise, raiserror

```
def in_progress_students(subject)
  case subject
    when "1,2,3 Roll!"
        started = students_by_completed(:worldOne, "1")[true] || []
        finished = completed_students(subject) || []
    when "If Fuzz, Then Roll"
        started = students_by_completed(:worldOne, "4")[true] || []
        finished = completed_students(subject) || []
    when "Loopy Lesson"
        started = students_by_completed(:worldOne, "19")[true] || []
        finished = completed_students(subject) || []
    when "Test Your Skillz"
        started = students_by_completed(:worldOne, "31")[true] || []
        finished = completed_students(subject) || []
    when "Functions101"
        started = students_by_completed(:worldTwo, "1")[true] || []
        finished = completed_students(subject) || []
    when "FunctionPro"
        started = students_by_completed(:worldTwo, "4")[true] || []
        finished = completed_students(subject) || []
    when "FunctionsPlus"
        started = students_by_completed(:worldTwo, "15")[true] || []
        finished = completed_students(subject) || []
    when "BuggyBasics"
        started = students_by_completed(:worldThree, "1")[true] || []
        finished = completed_students(subject) || []
    when "LoopyBugs"
        started = students_by_completed(:worldThree, "8")[true] || []
        finished = completed_students(subject) || []
    when "FunkyBugs"
        started = students_by_completed(:worldThree, "3")[true] || []
        finished = completed_students(subject) || []
    when "Infestation"
        started = students_by_completed(:worldThree, "11")[true] || []
        finished = completed_students(subject) || []
  end
      started.select{|student| !finished.include? student}
    end
```

I'm trying to refactor this code base by doing this:

```
IN_PROGRESS_LEVELS = {
  "1,2,3 Roll!" => [:worldOne, "1"],
  "If Fuzz, Then Roll" => [:worldOne, "4"],
  "Loopy Lesson" =>[:worldOne, "19"],
  "Test your Skillz" => [:worldOne, "31"],
  "Functions101" => [:worldTwo, "1"],
  "FunctionPro" => [:worldTwo, "4"],
  "FunctionsPlus" => [:worldTwo, "15"],
  "BuggyBasics" => [:worldThree, "1"],
  "LoopyBugs" => [:worldThree,"8"],
  "FunkyBugs" => [:worldThree,"3"],
  "Infestation" => [:worldThree, "11"]
}

def in_progress_students(subject)
  world, level = IN_PROGRESS_LEVELS[subject]
  started = students_by_completed(world, level)[true] || []
  finished = completed_students(subject) || []
  started.select{|student| !finished.include? student}
end
```

But I get an error, and I think it's because I'm getting a different output state. what am i doing wrong?

And also how could I fixed it by using raise error?

thank you

Comment: When you ask a question that involves an exception, please always say specifically what the exception was and on what line it occurred. We also probably need to see `students_by_completed`.  Lastly, please indent two spaces between `IN...` and `}` and between `def...` and `end`.  It's not necessary, but you'll get more respect.

Comment: You'll get more responses as well by having a nice indentation. It hurts my eyes and makes me lazy.

Comment: So, what's the different output state you're getting which differs from old code to new one?

Comment: Hey all, I was able to resolve the problem.  Thank you